# Samsung Galaxy Ace, data network mode keeps deactivating itself

Tags: data-connection

Every time i turn on my data network  it deactivates itself within 5 mins ,any ideas
anyone? i have a Samsung Galaxy ace.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have Battery Defender or some such app installed. You may have set data network to time out every 5 mins there (default is 15 mins).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will deactivate it but if you have set a data limit and then gone over it then the phone may be disabling the data connection to prevent you being charged extra.